# sharing a photo to twitter from an android app

Tags: android, image, twitter, share

in my app i am showing some photos which are uploaded to our local server. If the user likes the photos he can share it to twitter and thru email.

Is there any way to share a image to `email` when it is been stored in an `url`.

Following is my twitter code

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrepareRequestTokenActivity.class);
i.putExtra("imagetitle", imgtit);
i.putExtra("image_path", get_intent_path );
startActivity(i);
```

how could it be shared to a twitter wall

Comment: please share the solution if you figured it out.. @siva k

Comment: sorry i dint get a solution for this, just sharing only text in twitter....

Answer (score 0):

You can use twitter4j and can share photo and text. A sample code is given bellow.

```
public void Share_Pic_Text_Titter(File image_path, String message,
    Twitter twitter) throws Exception {
    try {
        StatusUpdate st = new StatusUpdate(message);
        st.setMedia(image_path);
        twitter.updateStatus(st);

    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        Log.d("Error==>", "Pic Upload error" + e.getErrorMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```